# Interpretation of ranef() using random effects and PLM package in R

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, random-effects

I'm running the following RE model on 33 countries aid donations to a given country using the following code:

```
plm(val_eur_sq ~ bse + t + t_sq, index="state",
                      model="random", cluster="state", data=balanced_panel_df))
```

Now, as I understand it the base plm model allows for intercepts to vary (in my case between countries), but not coefficients. When I use ranef() I get an interesting list that showcases how the countries differ (which I want), but I'm not exactly sure what output R has given me. The values seem much to big and too similar to the actual coefficient for the entire model to be intercepts.

What does the output that the ranef() command give say me when running a base RE model using `plm()`?

I found this forum link that discusses the same interpretation problem, but within the context of a mixed-model, and using lmer. That post says that ranef() gives "the conditional modes, that is the difference between the (population-level) average predicted response for a given set of fixed-effect values (treatment) and the response predicted for a particular individual", but this sounds like individual coefficients to me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.